Hip Roof converges 3 slopes into a single 1x2 drainage area. Rot results
I've got a HIP roof.  3 slopes converge into a 1' x 2' area.  I have a custom built gutter there, that constantly clogs with leaves, dirt, and sticks.  Literally almost impossible to reach into and clean out Every other month.  The trim in the area is rotten because of the drainage issue.  And the siding below down to the deck 2 stories below is rotting.  See drawing on the setup.
I am wondering how to fix the issue.  Would resloping one of the slops to get rid of the 3 point junction help?  See 2nd image.  Any other ideas?







It seems like the root cause is debris, which I don't expect re-sloping the roof will help much - if the downspout is clogged, it doesn't matter much what path water takes gets into the gutter. Maybe another type of leaf guard (it looks like you already have some) or a tool to clean the downspout from the ground?

I know of no way (nor did the gutter installers - who didn't install the bucket that catches the 3 slopes where the rot is) of having a leaf guard in the 1' x 2' "bucket" that the slopes converge into.   The 4" gutters runs right up to that "bucket".  There is the downspout for that bucket behind the cedar siding outcrop running right next to the white downspout.

What is going on in that last pic?  What's the gray thing running down the wall next to the white downspout—another downspout with some kind of chase?

Unfortunately this was an original design fail. The architect should've seen the problem coming and put function over form.
The right fix is to extend the two outer gable roof planes until they converge. This results in a large partial gable on the back of the house and a higher ridge, which may actually occur above your current main ridge, leaving a small hip extension up the front side.


You don't want to introduce mismatched slopes as your second image implies. The bent valleys and odd roof lines will destroy the aesthetic of your home. It'll look like an M.C. Escher drawing (if you're lucky). You'll also still have the problem of converging valleys.

This is a great answer but unfortunately the best part is "design fail".  Putting a big bay window next to an inside corner like that is crazy, and doing as suggested with the roof, Will really emphasize that the whole structure is out of place.  So as long as we're spending your money, :) do what he says with the roof, and also bring that whole area between the bay and the red door inside the house,  and change the other side of the bay to 90° instead of 30° to better match the new roof.
